# Cannot change Connection Information in admin interface

Tags: wp-admin

There are 11 plugin updates available for a WordPress site, so I tried updating it.

However, when I do that I get an error:

```
Public and Private keys incorrect for <username>
```

I have made keys for my own user on the server, but that is not the problem I am asking about.  The problem is that I cannot change any details in the Connection Information page (shown below).  There are details already there, but they cannot be changed.  I can select them, but I cannot delete or edit them.  I have tried in different browsers.

What could be causing this?  My WordPress account is set as an Administrator.

---

[image: Connection Information]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you have some or all of these defined somewhere, probably `wp-config.php`.

```
define('FTP_PUBKEY', '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub');
define('FTP_PRIKEY', '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa');
define('FTP_USER', 'username');
define('FTP_PASS', 'password');
define('FTP_HOST', 'ftp.example.org');
define('FTP_SSL', false);
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php

I am able to duplicate the issue and resolve it by manipulating those constants.